# i select a option from the dropdown.I have to show in other textbox, what i have chosen in the dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php

this is code :

```
<script>
(function() {

 // get references to select list and display text box
var sel = document.getElementById('clientName<?php $y=1; echo $y; ?>');
var el = document.getElementById('clientContac');


function getSelectedOption(sel) {
    var opt;
    for ( var i = 0, len = sel.options.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        opt = sel.options[i];
        if ( opt.selected === true ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return opt;
}

// assign onclick handlers to the buttons


document.getElementById('clientContac').onmouseover = function () {
    // access text property of selected option
    el.value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
}



}());   
</script>
```

```
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="clientContac" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Sub Amount</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientContac" name="clientContac"  onmouseover='sync()' />
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Please describe your problem more precisely.

Comment: use `onselect` for the event listener

Comment: You can use onchange event of dropdown